# Use a cookie on multiple level sub domain on apache php

Tags: php, apache, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to allow cookie share on multiple level subdomain like the following:
a.test.exaxple.com
b.test.example.com 
i want the cookie to be visible for both sub domains but not to the www.example.com
I've tried to set the cookie to ".test.example.com" like in normal subdomain but nothing..
how can I do it ?

Comment: Not all browser support this, see http://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: Did you set it to `*.test.example.com`, instead of `test.example.com` ?

Comment: We do not support ie 7 so its ok :) 
Thanks for your replay but my question was about two levels subdomain and the link you have shared is only one level.

Comment: @edvinas.me I have tried ".test.example.com", "*.test.example.com", "test.example.com" none of the above worked..